# Error al arrancar el servidor de NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs

Estoy empezando a desarrollar en el framework de [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) de manera autodidacta y siguiendo un [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391) dice que descargue o clone el repositorio de git lo cual ya descargue, siguiendo el tutorial llega una parte donde tengo que instalar **NPM**, lo cual hice descargando el ejecutable de **NodeJS**, instalando las siguientes versiones:

[image: Version de Node y NPM instalada]

siguiendo el tutorial me dice que tengo que ejecutar el siguiente comando:

> npm install

es aquí donde me marca el siguiente error:

[image: Error del comando]

Obteniendo el siguiente log:

[image: Log de ejecucion]

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.3
3 info using node@v6.7.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly install normalizeTree
8 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
9 silly loadIdealTree Starting
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
14 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
15 silly install loadShrinkwrap
16 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
17 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
18 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
19 silly fetchNamedPackageData fsevents
20 silly mapToRegistry name fsevents
21 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
22 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
23 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
23 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'fsevents',
23 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
23 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'fsevents',
23 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'fsevents',
23 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
23 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
23 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
24 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents
25 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents
26 verbose request no auth needed
27 info attempt registry request try #1 at 16:45:27
28 verbose request id 367ca189d7413f0c
29 verbose etag "69O0UF1UA8LG7BQRJME2P5RBR"
30 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents
31 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents
32 verbose headers { date: 'Wed, 05 Oct 2016 21:50:12 GMT',
32 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
32 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
32 verbose headers   etag: '"69O0UF1UA8LG7BQRJME2P5RBR"',
32 verbose headers   age: '283',
32 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
32 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-dfw1830-DFW',
32 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
32 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '5',
32 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1475704212.097764,VS0,VE0',
32 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
33 silly get cb [ 304,
33 silly get   { date: 'Wed, 05 Oct 2016 21:50:12 GMT',
33 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
33 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
33 silly get     etag: '"69O0UF1UA8LG7BQRJME2P5RBR"',
33 silly get     age: '283',
33 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
33 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-dfw1830-DFW',
33 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
33 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '5',
33 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1475704212.097764,VS0,VE0',
33 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding' } ]
34 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents from cache
35 verbose get saving fsevents to C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\fsevents\.cache.json
36 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
37 silly resolveWithNewModule fsevents@1.0.14 checking installable status
38 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Finishing
39 silly loadIdealTree Finishing
40 silly currentTree angular-seed@0.0.0
40 silly currentTree +-- accepts@1.1.4
40 silly currentTree | +-- mime-db@1.12.0

 silly generateActionsToTake Starting
43 silly install generateActionsToTake
44 silly generateActionsToTake Finishing
45 silly diffTrees action count 0
46 silly decomposeActions action count 0
47 silly executeActions Starting
48 silly install executeActions
49 silly doSerial global-install 0
50 silly doParallel fetch 0
51 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
52 verbose lock using C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-6383ae80e012e1e3.lock for C:\angular-seed\node_modules\.staging
53 silly doParallel extract 0
54 silly doParallel preinstall 0
55 silly doReverseSerial remove 0
56 silly doSerial move 0
57 silly doSerial finalize 0
58 silly doSerial build 0
59 silly doSerial global-link 0
60 silly doParallel update-linked 0
61 silly doSerial install 0
62 silly doSerial postinstall 0
63 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-6383ae80e012e1e3.lock for C:\angular-seed\node_modules\.staging
64 silly executeActions Finishing
65 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
66 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
67 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
68 silly install runTopLevelLifecycles
69 silly preinstall angular-seed@0.0.0 C:\angular-seed\angular-seed-e96d95ed
70 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~preinstall: angular-seed@0.0.0
71 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~preinstall: no script for preinstall, continuing
72 silly build angular-seed@0.0.0
73 info linkStuff angular-seed@0.0.0
74 silly linkStuff angular-seed@0.0.0 has C:\ as its parent node_modules
75 verbose linkBins angular-seed@0.0.0
76 verbose linkMans angular-seed@0.0.0
77 silly install angular-seed@0.0.0 C:\angular-seed\angular-seed-e96d95ed
78 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~install: angular-seed@0.0.0
79 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~install: no script for install, continuing
80 silly postinstall angular-seed@0.0.0 C:\angular-seed\angular-seed-e96d95ed
81 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: angular-seed@0.0.0
82 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
83 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\angular-seed\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\angular-seed\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\app\javier.castro\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\app\javier.castro\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\javier.castro\AppData\Roaming\npm
84 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: CWD: C:\angular-seed
85 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'bower install' ]
86 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
87 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
88 warn optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
89 warn notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
90 verbose stack Error: angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
90 verbose stack Exit status 1
90 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:242:16)
90 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
90 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
90 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
90 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
90 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
90 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
90 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
91 verbose pkgid angular-seed@0.0.0
92 verbose cwd C:\angular-seed
93 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
94 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
95 error node v6.7.0
96 error npm  v3.10.3
97 error code ELIFECYCLE
98 error angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
98 error Exit status 1
99 error Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
99 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
99 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
99 error not with npm itself.
99 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
99 error     bower install
99 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
99 error     npm bugs angular-seed
99 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
99 error     npm owner ls angular-seed
99 error There is likely additional logging output above.
100 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: hola bienvenido a SOes, te parece si copias y pegas el contenido del block de notas por favor? Saludos :D

Comment: ya inclui el log no se aprecia muy bien

Comment: listo hermano, editado :D se selecciona todo el contenido y se presiona el botón: { }

Comment: sería de utilidad que agregues el enlace del tutorial que estás siguiendo :D

Comment: estoy siguiendo el siguiente enlace: [https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391] y la versión de angular es la siguiente: [https://github.com/angular/angular-seed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta instalar git o ponerlo en el PATH

Se puede bajar de https://git-scm.com

Cuando pregunta si lo pone en el PATH hay que contestar que sí.

SI está instalado se puede intentar reinstalar poniendo sí para que modifique el PATH y reiniciar el equipo

Comment: de hecho git no lo tenia instalado, lo acabo de instalar reiniciare la maquina

Answer (score 1):

Debes saber que `npm` trabaja en conjunto con `git`. De hecho, si vas a la web de [NPM](https://npmjs.org) y buscas un repo, a menudo verás en la parte derecha un apartado que contiene la información del módulo/librería, entre ella el repositorio de la librería en GitHub.

[image]

Lo que hace NPM es hacer uso de git para clonar el repositorio de la librería y ponerlo dentro del directorio `node_modules/`.